# Why does ExecuteNonQuery stop working after two inserts?

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, sqlite-net

I have a problem with my sqlite requests.
I'm developing a tag system for some videos.

When I insert videos in my database, everything works fine but when it comes to tags and video_tag_link, I can only add one and the next one make my application freeze.

The problem doesn't come from the sql requests. I try them directly in a DB browser and they worked fine.

Here is the code I use to insert in the database :

```
try
{
            if (dbConnection == null)
                await InitDatabaseAsync();

            if (dbConnection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                await dbConnection.OpenAsync();

            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(query, dbConnection);
            await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

            onDataReturned?.Invoke(command.ExecuteReader());

            dbConnection.Close();
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            dbConnection.Close();
        }
```

Here is my request for the tag :

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO tags (name) VALUES ('Test Tag');
INSERT INTO tag_video_link (video_id, tag_id) VALUES (2, (SELECT id FROM tags ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1));
COMMIT;
```

I don't know how my test data generation that insert 100 of row worked perfectly but the insertion of 1 tag with the link to the video doesn't work.

I don't know if it's relevant but there is no call to the database in the onDataReturned.
It always close the connection before trying to make another request.

Can somebody help me ?

PS: Sorry if I made spelling mistakes or if I'm not very clear, I don't speak English often.

Comment: Your question has not all the informations required to fully understand it. What is _onDataReturned_? Why it can be null? Where is the point when the code sets it to null, or to something not null?

Comment: what do you mean by "make my application freeze"? Does an exception occur? If so, what is the exception and stacktrace?

Comment: May be escape sequences in video links or their lengths? Check the links..

Comment: @Steve : onDataReturned is an Action that can be null but it doesn't happend in this case. It just return the reader to create my entities in different classes.

Comment: @user1666620 : I don't know how to clarify it. My application just freeze.
It's very strange because my database functions are not handle in the ui thread.
Even more strange, I don't have any error message or any exception.
When the program make the first request, everything works but for the second, the program just freeze at "await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();". I doesn't crash, it doesn't close. Everything just freeze.

Comment: @Rekshino : The only tags I tried to insert were things like "aaaaaa". I tried multiple times and it always froze after the first successful insert.
The insert from the tag_video_link only contains 2 integers. I tried to hardcode them but it froze anyway.

Comment: So you have to post more code. See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit difficult to guess where things could go wrong with the given code sample but a 'using' construct may help to ensure that resources are released:

```
using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, conn))
    {
        await conn.OpenAsync();
        using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
        {
             onDataReturned?.Invoke(reader);       
        }
    }
}
```